# tensorflow: how to implement this complex mask operation

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor t1(rank 2) with shape [batch_size, data_size] as below：

```
|---------------|--------------|--------------|
|      1.0      |     2.0      |     3.0      |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|
|      4.0      |     5.0      |     6.0      |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|
|      7.0      |     8.0      |     9.0      |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|
```

and a indicator tensor t2(rank 1) with shape [batch_size] like this:

```
|---------------|--------------|--------------|
|      2        |     1        |     3        |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|
```

i want to implement a function(t1, t2) to output:

```
|---------------|--------------|--------------|
|      1.0      |     2.0      |     0.0      |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|
|      4.0      |     0.0      |     0.0      |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|
|      7.0      |     8.0      |     9.0      |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|
```

it looks like multiplying t1 with a mask defined by t2, but i cannot figure out how to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `tf.sequence_mask`. [See here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask). This basically implements creating the mask you are wondering about. Usage as follows:

```
mask = tf.sequence_mask(t2, dtype=tf.float32)
result = t1 * mask
```

If `dtype` is not given this would create a boolean mask which would likely result in problems when trying to multiply with `t1`, which is why we specifically ask for `float32`.

In case the maximum element in `t2` can be smaller than `data_size`, you should use

```
mask = tf.sequence_mask(t2, maxlen=data_size, dtype=tf.float32)
```

to prevent a shape mismatch between `t1` and `mask`.